# Rounding currency values (SwiftUI, Core Data)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, currency

I am trying to make a simple TextField in SwiftUI that will format provided values as valid value for currency. I need to round the value to 2 digits. And store the rounded value using Core Data (this I know how to do, I am using Decimal type, BTW).

So far I have this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var newValueAsString = ""
    @State private var value: NSDecimalNumber = 0
    
    let decimalBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("0", text: $newValueAsString, onCommit: {
                self.value = NSDecimalNumber(string: self.newValueAsString).rounding(accordingToBehavior: self.decimalBehavior)
                print("\(self.value)")
            }
            )
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                .font(Font.system(size: 30))
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            // Just to test. Later I will save the value to Core Data.
            Text("\(self.value)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

It doesn't work properly when iOS region uses commas instead of dots (for example, Poland). Decimal keyboard has "," not "." and when I use "," numbers are not rounded properly. 123,456 becomes 123. And with regions using dots (for example, USA) 123.456 becomes 123.46 as expected.

What am I missing here? My guess is NumberFormatter, but I cannot manage to make it work.

Comment: Note that it is. bad idea to store exchange rates with only 2 digits, take Japanese yen for instance that is something like 0.008 Euro or 0.009 USD

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out. So I should round decimals based on the currency? I need to research how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` can be initialized with a string & locale.
[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber/1409201-init) explicitly mentions that locale is used for interpreting the decimal separator (emphasis mine):

> **locale** : A dictionary (!) that defines the locale (specifically the decimalSeparator) to use to interpret the number in numericString.

So you could do something like:

```
// Here I am passing the current Locale but you should pass whatever makes sense to your input
self.value = NSDecimalNumber(string: self.newValueAsString, locale: Locale.current).rounding(accordingToBehavior: self.decimalBehavior)
```

Example:

```
print(NSDecimalNumber(string: "100.50", locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US"))) // => 100.5
print(NSDecimalNumber(string: "100,50", locale: Locale(identifier: "el_GR"))) // => 100.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and Locale.current it is very good solution for my purpose. One question, though. Is it possible to make it work with both . and , the same time? I mean we can have only one of these on decimalPad, but what if someone would write comm using physical keyboard when region uses dot on software keyboard?

Comment: @mallow I don't think that there is an API that would handle this for you automatically (but I may be wrong!). In that case, maybe manual validation would be required (what happens for example when inserts, or pasting text as well).

Comment: Yes, you are right about inserting text. It works to some extent. For example, 123a will return 123. But a123 will return NaN. I need to investigate more. But one problem less to solve already. Thank you! :)